# Why does the navigation bar type never move?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inXhs.png)

the sliders move normally but the bottom page bar stops on the first bullet and when I click on the others they emit an opaque colour.
I'm using swiperjs with data from a json where are the "products" type and with a fetch I try to put it in the slider.

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ysPj.png)

[js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNbnA.png)

use dynamicBullets but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Please, post your code as code, and not as an image. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).